Can’t switch to another logged-in user
Sonoma 14.5, Macbook Air M1 2020
Switching between logged in users works fine for a while (~10 minutes?) after rebooting, but then stops working. This includes via the lock/login screen, via touch-ID, and via fast-user-switching.
If I lock the screen, I see the last logged-in user and I can hover or key to the other user, but when I select the other user, the user disappears and the screen returns to the last logged-in user.
With fast switching, I can select another user, but it doesn’t do anything but close the selection window.
(I have seen others talk about experiencing this problem for years, but I couldn’t find it here and couldn’t find a solution anywhere.)
